# Nginx: Map URL to different path

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server

I would like to have my server serve files from a different path to the specific url.

Example:
`www.domain.com/some_catchy_name/image.jpg` should serve file from

`www.domain.com/docs/user/shared/pictures/image.jpg` or

relative file system path `/docs/user/shared/pictures/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
location ~ /pictures {
  root /var/www/docs/user/shared;
}
```

Answer to updated question

```
location ~ /some_catchy_name {
  root /var/www/docs/user/shared;
}
```

The location specifies a regular expression for the URL the browser requests. The root specifies the location on the file system.

You would probably benefit from reading an introduction to Nginx. I taught myself, it's not that complex if you have a technically inclined mind.

Comment: That worked, but I've updated my question. How to do it if it were a different name rather than "pictures".

Comment: @iBot updated answer